# Warning errors when adding line breaks to email?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email with a couple line breaks but every time I add `\r\n` and it keeps spitting out an error anyone know why it's doing this?

**ERROR**

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /home3/hutch/public_html/server1/ForgotPassword.php on line 24
>
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home3/hutch/public_html/server1/ForgotPassword.php on line 24
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home3/hutch/public_html/server1/ForgotPassword.php on line 24

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['Username'])){
        $Username = $_GET['Username'];

        if (is_dir("USERS/".$Username) === true) {

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Password.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
            $Password = fgets($myFile);
            fclose($myFile);

            require("PHP/class.phpmailer.php");
            require("PHP/class.smtp.php"); 

            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host     = "smtp.sulmaxmarketing.com";

            $mail->From     = "matt@sulmaxcp.com";
            $mail->FromName = "Online Game";
            $mail->AddAddress("sulmaxcp@gmail.com");

            $mail->Subject  = "Forgot Password";
            $mail->Body     = "You have requested your login details, if this is incorrect please reply to this email letting us know your account has been compromised.".\r\n."Username: ".$Username.\r\n."Password:".$Password;

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo 'Failed to send password to email. Please contact support.';
            }
            else {
                echo 'An email has been sent to your email address associated with the account.';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Username not found!'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You forgot quotes   . $var=$username."\n"."Hello";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap \r\n in double quotes like "\r\n".

Since it is part of the string that you want to add in your mail content.

And I must stress of using double quotes instead of single quotes since single quotes will not parse the escape characters \ and will simply print \r\n instead of a line break.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the system property for new line character, PHP_EOL.
Use the PHP_EOL constant, which is automatically set to the correct line break for the operating system that the PHP script is running on.

Note that this constant is declared since PHP 5.0.2.